# how to differentiate chart with colors

Tags: php, jquery, web, charts, chart.js

I want to differentiate "Men" and "Women" from this chart with colors. maybe we can make men chart with green colors and women chart with pink colors. 
here is my code

//data.php

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbintegrasi');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT JenisKelaminID, COUNT(JenisKelaminID) as jumlah FROM tahunmasukmagister GROUP BY JenisKelaminID");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
}

//freee memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//new print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

//app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var Gender = [];
            var jumlah = [];

            for(var i in data)
            {
                //Gender.push("Gender " + data[i].JenisKelaminID);
                if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 1)
                {
                    Gender.push("Men");
                } 
                else if(data[i].JenisKelaminID == 2)
                {
                    Gender.push("Women");
                } 
                else 
                {
                Gender.push("Other");
                }

                jumlah.push(data[i].jumlah);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: Gender,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label : 'Gender',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 300, 100, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: jumlah
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata

            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

could you please help me to solve those codes? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Chart.js documentation here:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart ,

You need to add the "attributes" for each label you have.

In your code, I assumes that you have 3 labels, which are Men, Women, and Other.

So as example, In your code :

```
datasets: [
                {
                    label : 'Gender',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 300, 100, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: jumlah
                }
            ]
```

there are only one "backgroundColor", "borderColor", "hoverBackgroundColor", and "hoverBorderColor", which is only for one label.

So what you should do is make each of the attributes as an array, like this:

```
backgroundColor: [
       'rgba(79, 181, 59, 1)', //green for men
       'rgba(239, 87, 196, 1)', //pink for women
       'rgba(166, 160, 164, 1)', //grey for other
],
```

Do it for other attributes like this.

Comment: thankyou. btw, above the chart there is a label that Gender has a green color. do you know how to add the label so that I can make a label that green for men and pink for women?

Comment: thankyou. btw, above the chart there is a label that Gender has a green color. do you know how to add the label so that I can make a label that green for men and pink for women? @afzafri

Comment: change the ```label : 'Gender'``` in the datasets, to your Gender array, like this ```label : Gender```. It should automaticcally follow the ```backgroundColor``` array that you set I guess

Comment: Also please mark my answer as the answer if you find it help you :)